# What is the opposite term of 'Socialization'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-difference, antonyms

The wikipedia definition of the term **'socialization'** is as follows :

> Lifelong process of inhereting and disseminating norms, customs and ideologies

I am looking for a term which will somewhat refer to 'reverse-socialization', or more like the undoing process of -the lifelong process of inhereting and disseminating norms, customs and ideologies- so to speak.

I thought about the term **'desocialization'** at first; but later got dissapointed when I looked up its definition. It provides with a more passive sense in a rather specific context.

Terms like **'alienation'** or **'isolation'** do not quite seem to fit in also, as they seem to fail in generalizing the 'undoing process' and do not necessarily refer to a *social context*, I assume?

Comment: I believe the verb is **to treadstone**  :)

Comment: I think "socialization" is a little complex to have an obvious opposite, you could use "isolation", or "separation" or "rejection of social norms" or "de-programming" or "shunning", depending on what specific social aspects you are rolling back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious antonym is **anti-socialization**. The [anti](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anti) prefix fits especially well because of the word *antisocial*.

For example:

- [Social Media's Anti-Socialization Myth](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141205234833-42120526-social-media-s-anti-socialization-myth)
- [Foundational Paradigms of Social Sciences](http://www.academia.edu/19730971/Foundational_Paradigms_of_Social_Sciences):

  > For the antisocialization paradigm, the goal of social science is to understand how a society drives agents to rebel against it and how agents strive to break the chains imposed by the society and thus dig the society’s grave.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at **individualization**.

> **individualize**
>   2. to mention, indicate, or consider individually; specify; particularize.

[TheFreeDictionaryOnline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/individualize)

(Note that *particularize* would be used in the sense of *To make particular as opposed to general or universal*.)